# Bitmap inside a bitmap

Tags: c#

I am trying to insert an image 800x500 inside a blank bitmap of 850x610 in the center. The inner image should be in the center and It also has a title on the top. I am attaching an image to illustrate my idea:

[image: Bordered Image inside another image/frame with a title]

```
public static Bitmap AddBorder(Bitmap srcImage)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(srcImage.Width + 45, srcImage.Height + 100);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    g.DrawImage(srcImage, 0, 0);
    g.DrawImage(srcImage, new Rectangle(bmp.Width - 1, 0, 1, bmp.Height));
    g.DrawImage(srcImage, new Rectangle(0, bmp.Height - 1, bmp.Width, 1));
    return bmp;
}
```

I have tried to draw it using drawRectangle, drawImage etc. But, I cannot pad it properly as illustrated in the above image. I also cannot add the border to inner image.
I want to get an idea about how to do that.

Comment: Please add your current code to your question.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I have added code where i tried to draw this border. I want to have an idea about how to do this and how to add text on top this border.

Comment: Can you tell us the bigger picture? Do you use WinForms or WPF? Are you planning to save this to a file or just to show it? Why you just don't use 2 Image controls and one textblock/label?

Comment: @SuRGeoNix I am using Bitmap to load the image and save it after doing all the processing on that Bitmap.

Comment: I will write a sample code soon for you. You need to measure also the text/string to properly align it.

Comment: There is a powerful DrawImage overload that takes two rectangles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below sample sets the new bitmap size, it fills it with a background (black), draws the image in the center and finally after measuring the text will align it in the center (width check only).

```cs
public static Bitmap AddBorder(Bitmap srcImage, string text)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(850, 610);

    using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        // Background
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));

        // Source Image
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(25, 55, 800, 500);
        g.DrawImage(srcImage, rect);

        // Border
        int borderThickness = 2;
        using(Pen pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(Brushes.Black, borderThickness))
        {
            pen.Alignment = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Inset;
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(rect.X - borderThickness, rect.Y - borderThickness, rect.Width + borderThickness, rect.Height + borderThickness));
        }

        // Text String
        using (Font font = new Font("Arial", 16))
        {
            SizeF size = g.MeasureString(text, font);
            g.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Black, new PointF((bmp.Width / 2) - (size.Width / 2), rect.Top - (size.Height + borderThickness)));
        }
    }

    return bmp;
}
```

Updated based on comments (Added also text above the centered image)!

Comment: I like the use of using for "g", brushes and also for the font (you forget dispose the font).

Comment: Well said... I never use using tho, I guess I don't like the tabs :)

Comment: Actually you can simply use Brushes.<anynamedColor> and won't need to dispose of them..

Comment: @SuRGeoNix thank you so much. This is exactly the thing I wanted. Is there any option that I can toggle to create a black border around the inner g.DrawImage(srcImage, rect)? I just changed the FillRectangle Color to White.

Comment: @SuRGeoNix there is a [using declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) in C#10 - no braces or indents

Comment: @AliAhmad No problem. I've updated with the border!

Comment: @SuRGeoNix Again thank you so much. I am new to C# and this was a tremendous help. Is there any resource to learn about Graphics in C#, aside from Documentation?

Comment: To be honest I've never used Graphics. My only experience is with DirectX for video playback. Understanding the rendering pipeline will give you a good base before going to higher level (eg. as .NET Graphics). DuckDuckGo is your friend I guess :)
P.S. Mark the answer as accepted so others will not read the question and try to answer it again.

Comment: @SuRGeoNix ah thanks for the suggestion. I will explore this line to thought a bit to see if it pans out for me.